# Neural Network stick in an unlearned state

Tags: neural-networks

Background: I want to apply a net to mapping from xyY color space to Munsell. The mapping in freely downloadable as a 5000+ entries table. I transformed the table data so that the Munsell Hue is given in degrees (0..360) and xy are given in angle and radius from the white point. I further transformed the data so the net doesn't have to figure mapping the Hue in 0..360° to 0..360° but rather from Hue 0..360° to delta Hue. I also rotated both Munsell and xy Hues so 0° is at yellow (10Y), where the delta Hue is negligible for all Values and Chromas. The data is formatted as a list of rules such as

`{9., 0.02, 2.} -> {-4.49066, 0.0633424, 1.16945}`.

I built and trained a neural net using the following statements:

```
MunsellAllNet = 
  NetChain[{3, LogisticSigmoid, 3, LogisticSigmoid, 3, 
    LogisticSigmoid}, "Input" -> 3];
MunsellAllNet = NetInitialize[MunsellAllNet];
TrainedAllNet = NetTrain[MunsellAllNet, MunsellNetData]
```

The net very quickly converges to a loss of around -2x10^2 and stops converging from there. And when I test the net with values, no matter the input values I provide, the result is always the same. So something doesn't look right.

I tried many more net configs with more or less layers and more or less neurons per layers with the same results. I did my master's degree on "Using Neural Netwoks for Detecting and Replacing Missing Values in Databases" some 20 years ago so I'm not new to neural nets and I expected at least an imperfect mapping.

So I'm probably missing something in my net specification and/or training attempt. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Using Mathematica 11.2.0.0.

Comment: This would be much easier to answer if the problem was actually reproducible. Can you add a random subset of the data (assuming the problem can be reproduced with a small subset). Might be something simple like bad input/output scaling. One thing you can check: a `LogisticSigmoid` output layer can only produce results between 0..1, so if the outputs are <0 or >1, maybe the net simply can't produce these values? Have you tried removing the last `LogisticSigmoid` layer?

Comment: @Niki Estner: Good point about the 0..1 range. I'll remove the last sigmoid and see what that gives. I'll work on getting and posting a subset of the data too.

Comment: Removing the last sigmoid already produces much more interesting results. Thanks for the observation. I will keep on working for transforming the data so both the inputs and outputs are in 0..1 range to help the net a little.

Comment: My personal rule of thumb is that I only use `LogisticSigmoid` for outputs if the output behaves more or less like a probability. I.e. you need a lot of evidence to get values near 0 or 1 (i.e. the absolute input to `LogisticSigmoid` has to be very large) and "learning happens" when the output is around 0.5 when the the gradient is largest - which fits the subjective probability intuition that p=0.5 means "I don't know" and thus the net should learn something while "p=1.0" means "I'm fairly certain" -> no learning necessary. For a color, brightness, location or angle, I wouldn't use a sigmoid

Comment: Try `Ramp` instead of `LogisticSigmoid` and more neurons in the hidden layers